# Узнать размер изображения в File Input

Tags: javascript

Как можно узнать размер изображения, выбранного в File Input еще до его загрузки?

Answer (score 3):

Например вот так. Выводит сразу после выбора файла.

```
    <input type="file" id="image" />

    $('#image').on('change', function() {
        alert(this.files[0].size);
    });
```

Для разрешения изображения:

```
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#image").on('change', function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: Это размер файла, а не изображения.

Comment: @cpp_user автор имел в виду разрешение изображения?

Comment: Да, разрешение, извините, неверно выразился.

Comment: Добавил для разрешения